# React-admin : Reference Input doesn't display my fields only displays ids

Tags: typescript, reference, react-admin

I have a Reference input of react admin which displays ids of the resource and not the field i ask to (status) and i don't understand why. That's my code

```
const CandidatureFilters = [
  <SearchInput source="q" alwaysOn />,
   <ReferenceInput source="status" label="Candidature status" reference="candidatures"/>
];
```

What it displays : [reference input display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IWWA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem must be in the shape of the records being populated by the `ReferenceInput` to its children (an [`AutocompleteInput`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AutocompleteInput.html#usage)). Each record must have the following shape: `{ id, name }`, where the `name` field is going to be used as the text to be displayed and the `id` as the value

Read the following https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AutocompleteInput.html#using-in-a-referenceinput

Hope that helps

Comment: No my API send me a JSON like {{id: 1 , name:" test", status:"1"}} so i dont understand why it doesn't work, but it works on datagrid and not on referenceInput

Comment: Without a code example, I cannot know why It doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

source is not the name of the field you want to display. It is the name of the foreign key that identifies the record you are interested in. In this case it should be something like candidature_id.
Reference should be the name of the foreign table from which you are pulling the data.
Since you want to display a field that is not (I presume) set as the record representation when you declare the resource, then you will need something like:

```
<ReferenceInput label="Candidature status" source="candidature_id" reference="candidatures">
    <AutocompleteInput optionText="status" />
</ReferenceInput>
```